# qDebug outputs QString UTF-8 non-Ascii symbols as like \uxxxx

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, qstring, qdebug

I am trying to convert string (QString) in unicode to utf-8.

qDebug prints string like this:

> "Fault code soap:Client: \u041F\u043E\u043B\u044C\u0437\u043E\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043B\u044C \u0441 \u0438\u0434\u0435\u043D\u0442\u0438\u0444\u0438\u043A\u0430\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043E\u043C \u00AB16163341545811\u00BB \u043D\u0435 \u043D\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043D"

I have tried using `QTextCodec` like this but it outputs same unreadable string:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QString readableStr = QString::fromUtf8(codec->fromUnicode(str));
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I wonder what is going on but it happens when `qDebug` prints `QString`...

The following code

```
qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("тест") << "тест" << QString::fromUtf8("тест").toUtf8().data();
```

prints out:

"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442" тест тест

Comment: And what is the input? What do you have in `str` initially?

Comment: Funny thing... `qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(yourOutput);` printed me `Fault code soap:Client: Пользователь с идентификатором «16163341545811» не найден` using linux and utf-8 as default codec for sources. Your `QTextCodec` code changed nothing.

Comment: Hmmm I am on linux:

locale -a outputs:
C
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8

And in main I set:
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

Comment: It seems to me the string is already in `UTF-8` encoding. Are you trying to convert `UTF-8` into `UTF-8` twice? Also make sure your console is set to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact thread on the Qt mailing list, but this behaviour was recently introduced, as qDebug is originally meant to debug an objects internal state. Non ASCII characters are now put out like this, which most people seem to dislike, but the developer or maintainer responsible wants to keep it this way.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is the reason!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the variable str has type QString. Your readableStr has the same contents as str. UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode strings that uses 8 bit characters, that can be stored in a QByteArray. qDebug uses some special functions to display string in an console or debugging buffer to help you understand the contents of the string. If you put a QString in any GUI element you will see the expected readable content.

Comment: Yeah you are right, str is a QString.

I need to have readable output in console, it's not GUI application.

Comment: Try: std::cout << str.toUtf8().data(); // or std::cerr